¿Como resolver el error de sintaxis numero 42601 en PGADMIN 4 cuando creo una función?
El código en cuestión es este. EL error especificamente me pone que se ecuentra en los simbolos $$ después del END. He probado ya de todo y el chatGPT no me lo sabe solucionar.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insertar_trigger() 

RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$$

    DECLARE 
        id_generat VARCHAR;
    BEGIN
        SELECT CONCAT('A', nextval(sequencia_id) INTO id_generat
        NEW.id_actor := id_generat;

        RETURN NEW

    END;
 
$$

LANGUAGE plpgsql;


Tu error esta en que faltan varios ; pero también puedes simplicar un poco tu código  evitando esa variable y ese INTO de más, pues al final puedes hacer tu concatenación y asignarla a la variable especial NEW directamente, por ejemplo:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mayuscula_nombre() RETURNS trigger AS
$$

BEGIN
        NEW.id_actor:= (SELECT CONCAT('A', nextval(sequencia_id)));
        RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

